# Уровни косвенного обращения СИ

Tags: c, строки

Перебираю строку и хочу текущий символ склеить с другой строкой, но показывает предупреждение

"const char *" отличается по уровням косвенного обращения от "char"

а при компиляции ошибку в strcat

Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x7889C573 (ucrtbased.dll) в Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000030.

массив сс заполненн данными из файла.

```
char cc[368];
char number[5] = "0";

for (int i = 0; i < 368; i++) {
    if (cc[i] == ';'){
        continue;
    }
    else {
        strcat(number, cc[i]);
        if (cc[i+1] == ';') {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Всем спасибо. Как и сказал @dIm0n. strcat не работает с одним символом. В итоге преобразовал символ в строку и склеил 2 строки. Получилось:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 368; i++) {
    if (cc[i] == ';'){
        memset(number, 0, 5);
        continue;
    }
    else {
        char cToStr[2];
        cToStr[1] = '\0';
        char currentChar = cc[i];
        cToStr[0] = currentChar;
        strcat(number, cToStr);
        if (cc[i+1] == ';') {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Советую таки на английском ошибки и предупреждения оставить, ну а по вопросу смотрите объявление strcat, он не принимает одиночный `char` https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat

Comment: @dIm0n, а как таки добавить один символ к строке?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4834811/13970074

Comment: @dIm0n, спасибо. в итоге преобразовал символ в строку и склеил :)

Comment: Можете ответить на свой вопрос, если хотите, чтобы в будущем люди могли видеть, как это делать

Comment: да, спасибо. уже добавил ответ в описании

Comment: Не, вот как раз в **вопрос** добавлять ответ не надо, а надо именно в **ответы** :) Для этого внизу есть специальная кнопка "ответить на собственный вопрос" или типа того

Answer (score 2):

Ну, вообще-то, тогда уж

```
strncat(number, &cc[i],1);
```

только вот не вижу я, чтоб в `cc` хранилось что-то не мусорное (вы же ее не инициализируете?), а в `number` хватало места (сейчас вы можете добавить в нее не более 3 символов).

Comment: в сс есть данные. они считаны из файла

Comment: Зато у number длина 5 вместе с нулём.